# When an account has expired, trigger set that the account owner made is autimatically removed from triggers?

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, account

My coworker left our company, so his account will be expired in a few days.
I wondering triggers that he made in a google apps script are removed automatically?

I have an access to edit the scripts he made, but why I cannot delete triggers of the scripts?

Comment: It's not possible to manage other people's triggers with your script.

Comment: Are you the admin of the domain? Was this a shared project?

Comment: @Jescanellas Yes, It was a shared project. But now I solved this problem : When someone's account is expired, the triggers he/she had added are seen as 'disable' and not executed. So I added new triggers on the scripts. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: Great, I'm adding the solution as a community wiki answer for anyone who has the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments, when someone's account is disabled (not deleted) their triggers are not executed anymore.